# Big Entity Framework write operation failing in Azure App Service, works in local VS

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

This is in an Azure App service, C#, ASP.NET, Azure SQL environment. The issue appears there ("Production"), but not in my local VS development system ("Local Dev").

The task is to copy a "data set" consisting of several cross-indexed files from the Azure SQL database back into the database, with all the links fields updated with new record IDs. The data set is exported as an encrypted XML file, and then imported, decrypted, and re-translated back into table records, which are added back into the database. Works fine, except for one relatively large data set (about 2000 records in four files). And that "import" works in my local development environment, but fails in Production.

It DOES work in Production when I do a "copy" instead of an import/export. The copy does not do the encrypt/decrypt, however, that does not appear to be the specific issue, because the whole export/import works in Local Dev. The main work of the import, after decryption and translating from XML, is done by creating all the appropriate records with the new IDs in EF and then committing the write to disk.

It takes an annoyingly long time (maybe 15 minutes) on my Local Dev, and the successful "Copy" on the production app service, eventually completed within probably 30 minutes. That was with an S1 service and an S1 Azure SQL database. However the import still failed in Production when I increased both the app service and disk server by a notch.

So, my guess is that somehow the EF processing is timing out in Production, and not on my Local Dev. The overall session timeout on production, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout`, is set to 180 minutes, and that's observed externally, so I don't believe that is the issue.

There's no way to rewrite the main code of the import function at this time.

My question is: what might be features of the Azure App Service Production environment that would cause the big EF data assembly and write to time out or give up, that would not be on my Local Dev?